# sql subquery returns more than on 1 row error

Tags: sql, woocommerce, subquery, mariadb

```
SELECT wp_terms.name AS 'Exam',   
       (SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
        FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key in ('_order_total') ),  
       wp.id,  
       wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value AS 'Product Id',  
       f.order_item_name,
       (SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
        FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key in ('_billing_email'))  
FROM wp_term_taxonomy
  INNER JOIN wp_terms ON wp_terms.term_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id  
  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id  
  INNER JOIN wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta ON wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value = wp_term_relationships.object_id  
  INNER JOIN (SELECT f.order_item_id,  
                     f.order_id,  
                     f.order_item_name  
              FROM wp_woocommerce_order_items f) f ON f.order_item_id = wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.order_item_id  
  INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_postmeta.post_id = f.order_id  
  INNER JOIN (SELECT wp.id,  
              FROM wp_posts wp
                INNER JOIN wp_postmeta wm ON wp.id = wm.post_id  
              WHERE wp.post_type = 'shop_order'  
              AND   wp.post_status = 'wc-completed'  AND   wm.meta_key = '_completed_date') wp ON wp.id = wp_postmeta.post_id  
WHERE wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'product_cat'  
AND   wp_term_taxonomy.term_id IN (2825,2829,2833,2837,2844,2851,2847)  
AND   wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_key = '_product_id'  
AND   wp_postmeta.meta_key IN ('_order_total','_billing_email')
```

The above sql query throws subquery returns more than one row error. I want billing address in column and order total in another column. How to do that?

Comment: is the _billing_email and _order_total just 1 row? or you want to combine all those rows as 1 value per selected record?, perhaps you can do left join of wp_postmeta instead of putting it in Select, 
for ex:
SELECT ...,  _billing_email, .... FROM .......
LEFT JOIN (SELECT STRING_aggregate_function( wp_postmeta.meta_value, ',') as _billing_email WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key in ('_billing_email')) ON id = id....

Comment: Thanks for the reply, _billing_email and _order_total are different meta keys having different meta values in same table. I want both of the meta values in different columns.

Comment: It is MariaDB @aleksej

Answer (score 0):

As vims said, you've more than one row in the 2 subselects from wp_postmeta.
In fact you don't join them by an id or something like that and the following select, for example

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
    FROM wp_postmeta
    WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key in ('_order_total')
```

will return all rows in the DB with key ='_order_total'

The same holds for

```
SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
        FROM wp_postmeta
        WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key in ('_billing_email'))
```

So, you should add a join clause on some id, to both of them.
I'm sorry I'm not expert on WP and\or WooCommerce, so I can0't give you an hint on which field use.

Moreover you should put those subselects in the FROM and WHERE part or your select. A subselect in the selectlist is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

The subqueries are not limited to the `post_id` in question.  Hence, you are getting the `order_totals` for all the posts.  Add something like this to each subquery:

```
AND f.order_id = post_id
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT
    wp_terms.name AS 'Exam',   
    (
     SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
     FROM wp_postmeta
     WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key in ('_order_total')  and rownum=1
    ),  
    wp.id,  
    wp_woocommerce_order_itemmeta.meta_value AS 'Product Id',  
    f.order_item_name,
    (
     SELECT wp_postmeta.meta_value
     FROM wp_postmeta
     WHERE wp_postmeta.meta_key in ('_billing_email') and rownum=1
    )  
FROM
    wp_term_taxonomy
....
```

Comment: Try to add explanatory text with what the problem was, and what you have done in order to solve the problem.

Comment: MySQL does not have `rownum`, only `LIMIT`.